# Server Resource Management service (srmsvc) event id 8197 is logged every 10 seconds

Tags: disk-volume, windows-storage-server

I am running a Windows Server 2012 Storage Edition server as a file server and am getting Event ID 8197 logged in my Application event log every 10 seconds.  The message from the error is:

> RtlCreateSystemVolumeInformationFolder on volume C:?\Volume{5c286810-f966-41c6-be33-4c511d7103cd} returned 0x5, 0x8000ffff, Catastrophic failure

I have looked at a few articles on social.technet.microsoft.com [like this one](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ea70e322-873c-499c-b48d-94bc386bd4e4/srmsvc-error-8197?forum=winserver8gen) and elsewhere and they have been of no help.  A System Volume Information folder **does** exist on my C: drive and the System account does have Full permissions to it.

Also, I'm not familiar with finding a volume based upon the symbolic linking (?) name, so I'm not sure how to translate C:?\Volume{...} into something I can look for.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?  TIA

Comment: I have found that the volume referred to is the "F:" drive on that machine.  Also, I found that the System Volume Information folder on that drive has an SRM folder which the Administrator account cannot access.  I believe there are some messed up ACL's on this folder, or the folder is corrupt in some way.  The Administrator account cannot even take ownership of the folder, nor get owner information.